# How to press button in View #1 to change the Label in View #2 (Xamarin iOS)

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I when I press a button in view #1 (for example "PurpleFruitBtn") and I want to change the text in another view down the line (after a few other screens of other things) to display "Selection: Grape."

Have tried a few things, but they don't work.

How would more experienced people that know what they are doing do it?

Thanks,
A humbled kid who knows more and more that he doesn't know much.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a string variable in View#2, and then put it in View#1 when you're switching to View#2，like this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZO4Wu.png)

When the page switch is complete, the label on the second page takes the variable of PhoneNumbers and displays it.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a common class for transferring data between views:

```
using System;  
namespace XamarinIosDataPass {  
    public class CommonClass {  
        public static string value;  
    }  
}
```

Then when in view1, you update data when button is clicked:

```
partial void BtnSend_TouchUpInside(UIButton sender) {  
            CommonClass.value = txtInput.Text;  
        }
```

And update the lable in View2 based on value of the Common class:

```
public override void ViewDidLoad() {  
            base.ViewDidLoad();  
            lblDisplay.Text = CommonClass.value;  
        }
```

Please refer this [link](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-pass-data-between-two-viewcontroller-in-xamarin-ios/) for more details.

Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `NSNotification`  to send message and pass value between two views.

> in View #1

post the notification when you want to change the label in view#2

```
UIButton button = new UIButton(new CGRect(100, 300, 100, 50));
button.SetTitle("PurpleFruit",UIControlState.Normal);
button.SetTitleColor(UIColor.White, UIControlState.Normal);
button.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Blue;
button.TouchUpInside += (sender, e) =>
  {

   NSDictionary dic =NSDictionary.FromObjectAndKey(new NSString("value"),new NSString(button.TitleLabel.Text)) ;

   NSNotification notification = NSNotification.FromName("ChangeValue",null,dic); //pass the string as a parameter

   NSNotificationCenter.DefaultCenter.PostNotification(notification);

  };
```

> in view #2

Register the notification in the method `ViewWillAppear`

```
public override void ViewWillAppear(bool animated)
  {
    base.ViewWillAppear(animated);

    NSNotificationCenter.DefaultCenter.AddObserver(this,new Selector("ChangeValue:"),new NSString("ChangeValue") ,null);
  }

 [Export("ChangeValue:")]
 public void ChangeValue(NSNotification notification)
   {
     Console.Write(notification.UserInfo.ObjectForKey(new NSString ("value")));
     // now you can change the label.text 
   }
```

> Notice :the name of notification must be same (just like `ChangeValue` in above code). Before posting you should register the notification firstly.Otherwise,view #2 can't receive the notification.

For more details about NSNotification you can refer to [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsnotification?language=objc)